# Android checking if hashmap has data before the data is actually placed in the hashmap

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, hashmap, firebase-realtime-database

I have an application that is checking against points of interest stored in a Firebase database. Each user has their own specific interests in genres which affects what is displayed on the map.

To analyse these interests that each user has, I take their interests from the database and place them in a hashmap specific to the user. 
Within the user's constructor I call the setInterests() method which actually performs the setting of the data within the HashMap.

I also have a method within the User class that checks the contents of the user's `interestMap` for a specific genreID. If they have it, return true, if they don't, return false. I also check if the hashmap is empty, and if it is, I want to display all data. However, when the `hasInterest()` method is called, the user's interestMap has not yet been set. `setInterets()` is called in the User constructor, with the user instance being created in my `MapActivity`'s onCreate.

---

User Constructor

```
public User(String username){
    this.username = username;
    interestMap = new HashMap<>();
    setInterests();
}
```

---

Has Interest Method

```
// Check if the user has the listed interest
public boolean hasInterest(final long genreId){
    String id = String.valueOf(genreId);

    System.out.println("Has Interest: " + interestMap);
    // If the user has no interests, display the listed interest
    if(interestMap.isEmpty()){
        Log.d(TAG, "User has  no interests, showing all " + interestMap.get(id));
        return true;
    }

    Object interest =  interestMap.get(id);
    // If the user does not have the listed interest, don't display it
    if(interest == null){
        Log.d(TAG, "User does not have interest in this, not showing data");
        return false;
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "User has interest in Genre"+ interestMap.get(id)+ ", showing data");
    return true;
}
```

---

Set Interests method

```
 public void setInterests() throws DatabaseException{

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users/" + getUid()+"/interests");
    try{
        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot interestSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    String interestKey = interestSnapshot.getKey();
                    Object interestValue = interestSnapshot.getValue();

                    Log.d(TAG, "Key = " + interestKey + "; Value = " + interestValue);
                    push(interestKey, interestValue);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Could not access data: ", databaseError.toException());
                Log.d(TAG, "Error Code: " + databaseError.getCode());
            }
        });
    }catch(DatabaseException e){
        Log.w(TAG, "Database Exception " + e);
    }
    System.out.println(interestMap);
}
```

---

Map Activity On Create method

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkLocationPermission();
    }
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    user = new User(auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());
```

---

Where the Has Interest method is called within the Maps OnLocationChanged

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Inside onDataChange");
            for (final DataSnapshot poiSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                final String mPoiSnapshot = poiSnapshot.getKey();
                // Get data from Firebase
                final String mPoiTitle = (String) poiSnapshot.child("title").getValue();
                final String mPoiStory = (String) poiSnapshot.child("story").getValue();
                final long mPoiGenreID = (long) poiSnapshot.child("Genre/ID").getValue();
                final String mPoiGenreType= (String) poiSnapshot.child("Genre/Type").getValue();

                final POIGenre mPoiGenre = new POIGenre(mPoiGenreID, mPoiGenreType);

                if(user.hasInterest(mPoiGenreID)) {
```

---

For some reason, this `hasInterest()` is called before my User is actually created. I have tried creating my user within the OnLocationChanged method, where `hasInterest()` is actually called, as a debug method, but that didn't affect anything.

Here is my debug that is produced where I print out my `interestMap`'s contents and what is in it when the `hasInterest()` method checks it.

```
 I/System.out: Has Interest: {}
 D/******* USER user@user.com: User has  no interests, showing all null
 I/System.out: Has Interest: {} 
 D/******* USER user@user.com: User has  no interests, showing all null
 I/System.out: Has Interest: {}
 D/******* USER user@user.com: User has  no interests, showing all null
 I/System.out: Has Interest: {}
 D/******* USER user@user.com: User has  no interests, showing all null
 D/******* USER user@user.com: Key = 1; Value = Historical
 I/System.out: {1=Historical}
```

At the end you can see that the Historical genre from my Firebase is being placed in the `interestMap`

Am I just missing something painfully obvious? Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Data is loaded from the Firebase database asynchronously. This means that by the time you print the interests, the data hasn't been loaded yet. I recommend reading more about this in the top answers from this list: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bandroid%5d%5bfirebase-database%5d%20asynchronous

Comment: Ah, that clears it up, looks like I'm going to have to delve into some asynchronous wizardry. Thanks for the tip.